# Struggling with whether its $\pm p dV $

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am struggling to understand when calculating the work done by a gas whether it is postive or negative p. It my notes and in many other notes sometimes it is $-pdV$ and sometimes it is $pdV$.

I think I have come up with a way to rectify this and it would be to compute the work done using $p dV$ then add a minus afterwards if necessary to make it comply with the first law.

Is this a good way of dealing with it or is there a better way of deciding whether it should be $\pm p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign is governed by the convention - whether the volume is of your system in consideration or not.

If you decrease the volume of your system - you increase the energy of your system, so you require for total energy change to be positive.

If the volume is describing your system then $ dV <0 $ and so $dE=-PdV>0$ is the correct expression

If the volume is the volume outside the system then $ dV>0 $ and then $dE= +PdV >0 $ is the correct expression

Comment: I have the $E=\frac{f}{2}pV$ which would imply that increasing volume increases the energy? This doesnt agree with your second sentence?

Comment: Your comment is about slightly different thing. Even for non-ideal gas $ E=E(S,V,N) $ so $E(S,V,N)=\frac{f}{2} p(S,V,N) \cdot V $. Because of the dependence of preassure on entropy and volume - you cannot state apriori from that formula that for greater volume the energy is greater. (It depends for example on the process by which the volume expanded - adiabatic or not). I talked about the 1st law of thermodynamics which seperates the change in energy by doing work on the system ( $d W=-PdV $ ) and heat transfer ($ d Q $ )

Comment: How do you justify the second sentence then? Also I only seem to ever consider the volume of the gas which is doing work or has done work on it so I cannot see when you would have the case of your last sentence

Comment: $ dE=-PdV=\frac{f}{2}(PdV+VdP) $ then $-(1+\frac{2}{f}) \frac{dv}{v}=\frac{dp}{p} $ and finaly you get $ pv^{\frac{2+f}{f}}=const $ which is the poisson equation for ideal gas (adiabatic prosess, as initialy stated by $ dE=-PdV $)